# Psexec executed cmd to run further programs which require user input

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a small problem with my Powershell script.

What do i want:
open CMD via PSEXEC on a remote machine, and work in this "remoteshell" as if i am in front of this machine. There is a commandline tool which i'd like to run, which requires user input after its started (it runs a own "shell")

What the problem is:
i utilize PSEXEC 2.11 with the following command

.\PSEXEC \\$Global:Endpoint -s -accepteula cmd

- Cmd gets started as expected.
- When i enter the name of the tool (lets call it tool.exe) the inital screen is loaded. But when the shell appears, nothing happens. I can enter commands but there will be no feedback...

C:\windows\System32>tool.exe

Testing Tool V1.0

Command? >

Then nothing can be entered anymore...

I even cannot stop it by pressing CTRL+C. I need to close the application window to force it to close. :(

Any ideas? Are there programs which cannot run in "user interaction" mode?
For reasons, it cannot run as a window visible on the remote endpoint. It needs to run silent.

Comment: I tried the following, in lieu of tool.exe, netsh.exe: `$Global:endpoint = "192.168.192.1"
.\PSEXEC \\$Global:Endpoint -s -accepteula cmd
`": no problem from Powershell CLI, however it did not work from ISE (well, not sure where it was reading input from and sending output to).

Comment: hi. CMD works for me. i will get a remote prompt. but as soon as i enter "tool.exe" in remote CMD prompt. i can see tool loading, but it doesnt accept any new user input (it seems as the piped in/output is not getting sent to tool or something).